# How to use node modules in Laravel5.2 assets file

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-5, web3js

This time I am trying to use a npm web3 package in laravel 5.2 project. I am completely new using npm and that too inside laravel.

So far I have below things in my package.json file -

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^2.0.0",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36"
  }
}
```

When I do `npm install` all the node dependencies are installed in `node_modules` inside root directory. Now I am trying to figure out how this packages can be bought in use inside `public/assets/js/app.js` file.

Do I also have to make node services running to use this packages?

**npm version: 6.4.1

node version: v8.11.4**

Your help is much appreciated.

## **Updated question - 10th Sep 2018**

Downgraded my node package to 6.0 due to overcome few issues with 8.0 I was facing.

**node version: v6.0.0**
**npm version: 3.8.6**

New package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.9.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir-rollup": "^0.3.3",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack": "^1.0.1",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36"
  }
}
```

New gulpfile.json:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var path = require('path');
require('laravel-elixir-webpack');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.webpack(
        './node_modules/web3/src/index.js',
        './public/js/web3-compiled.js'
    );
});
```

When I run `npm run dev` in console, it stops finishes as below -

```
[digvijay@Digvijays-MacBook-Air:/var/www/html/estatebaron$ npm run dev

> @ dev /private/var/www/html/estatebaron
> gulp watch

node_modules/nan
[17:10:07] Using gulpfile /private/var/www/html/estatebaron/gulpfile.js
[17:10:07] Starting 'watch'...
[17:10:07] Finished 'watch' after 18 ms
```

What I am expecting here is a js file name `web3-compiled.js` created in `public/js` directory, but that does not happen now. Am I missing anything here.

Comment: Are you using Laravel elixir,  Laravel mix, something else, or nothing to compile your assets?

Comment: Nothing as of now I guess. I actually don't know how to do. But I believe laravel mix is for laravel version higher that 5.3.

Comment: It might be worth watching this video to get you started https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/6

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but didn't solve the problem yet.
I am updating my answer with current problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default laravel 5.2 configuration you're probably missing some lines in `package.json` [see this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/package.json)

So to make it work run `npm run dev`, but make sure to configure your gulp correctly with `gulpfile.js`. Read more about this in the https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir and https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/v3.9.1/docs

Comment: Thanks @Vladyslav, I followed this but stuck with a problem which I have updated in my question.